# Using tinylog with two console writers in parallel

Tags: java, tinylog

I am using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tinylog/tinylog-api/2.2.0 in our project.

I can configure my writer format the following way:

```
Configuration.set("writer", "console");
Configuration.set("writer.format", "{level}: {class-name}.{method}(): {message}");
```

But now I need a different output format for some loggers.

Is this possible with tinylog? If yes, can someone provide a short example how to do this?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tags (https://tinylog.org/v2/configuration/#tags):

```
Configuration.set("writer1", "console");
Configuration.set("writer1.tag", "A, B");
Configuration.set("writer1.format", "{class-name}: {message}");

Configuration.set("writer2", "console");
Configuration.set("writer2.tag", "C");
Configuration.set("writer2.format", "{level}: {message}");
```

Tagged loggers can be created via `TaggedLogger logger = Logger.tag("A")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the hint in the right direction. Actually I realized that I also use slf4j loggers, but in the end I managed to map them to my standard logger.

Comment: You can also use markers for SLF4J loggers. These makers will be mapped to tinylog's tags.